# How to pass the relative file path of a file in the src/main/resource folder of a Spring Boot webapp?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, ftp

I'm trying to access a specific file in my resource folder, grab that uri, convert it to a toString, and then use that to be able to send that file to a server via ftp. Below is the code I'm currently using to attempt it, but I keep getting a FileNotFoundException for it. If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, or offer an alternative way to do this, that'd be fantastic!

[image]

```
@Value("classpath:submitTest.txt")
private Resource res;

private String submitJcl(FTPClient ftp, String serverName) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(res.getURI().toString());
    ftp.storeFile(serverName, inputStream);  

    return result;
}
```

Error:

```
2020-05-13 09:04:25.353 ERROR 11472 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] c.cat.pis.service.CnlLetterServiceImpl   : java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\mallid2\eclipse-new-PIS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Product%20Information%20System%20(PIS)\WEB-INF\classes\submitTest.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() for getting files from Resource folder, like

```
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("submitTest.txt").getFile();
```

Or if you need inputStream then you can use:

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("submitTest.txt");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, the inputStream is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly. Thank you!